# Configuring load balancer to forward request to a specific machine in cluster

Tags: sockets, cookies, load-balancing, scalability

I have cluster of server and there is some communication over sockets, so if a client A connects on server A, then other participating client B (say it has been invited by A) should also connect on server A.
I know the typical cookie based stickiness, if client A establishes session on server A, I can drop a cookie and configure load balancer to connect the client always to server A -but this does not guarantee that Client B also connects to ServerA!

Here is my scenario

1. Load balancer is round robin
2. Say we have three servers ServerA, ServerB and ServerC
3. Client A request is handled by ServerA -it creates a socket there
4. Client B request goes to ServerB -HERE, I need it to redirect to ServerA where socket has been created
5. If I use redirect, it will pass through Load Balancer and ServerC will be selected (Atleast it's not guaranteed that ServerA will be selected)
6. I do not want to reveal the real IP -otherwise I can do a redirect directly

My Question -is there a way that while "rerouting" the request for client B in step 4, I can specify some header or parameter so that LoadBalancer does not apply round robin there instead based on the parameter redirects it to a specific IP?

Some sort of key value pair -key is the request path/param/header and some IP is mapped to an IP at load balancer level?

Comment: It's an interesting case , but may i ask why do you want to let the Client B route to Server A instead of B or C if it get invited by Client A .. because i think if your app servers is well configured and sessions plus database is shared between servers properly,  you don't have to do that.

Comment: As I have mentioned, its "Socket", which cannot be shared

Comment: Seems this is possible with HAPROXY configuration which supports a lot of routing algorithms, but not other proxies. I was looking for such stuff in AWS ELB, but its not possible there.